# Does anyone know the answer the following questions on converting logical - physical addresses

Tags: scheduling

Due to the unforeseen pandemic, I am unable to speak to my tutor about the following question. I have emailed him, but I have not had an answer for weeks. Can someone please enlighten me.

Image and question to be answered below. Please provide an explanation, as I am struggling to find an answer:

[image]

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are the statement of an exercise-style problem and a request for someone to solve it for you.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Can you credit the original source for all copied material?